# Why am I not getting any output from the pong.kv file?

Tags: kivy

I'm learning kivy and doing the pong tutorial. All I get is a black window.  I added a print('test') in the pong.kv file and received an error, so the main.py file is finding pong.kv.  Both files are in the same directory.  I'm using python v3.6 and kivy v1.10.0

Question - Why am I not getting any output from the pong.kv file?

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.graphics import Rectangle


class PongGame(Widget):
    pass


class pongApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return PongGame()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    pongApp().run()
```

This is the pong.kv file,

```
#:kivy 1.10.0

<PongGame >:
    canvas:
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.center_x - 5, 0
            size: 10, self.height

    Label:
        font_size: 70
        center_x: root.width / 4
        top: root.top - 50
        text: "0"

    Label:
        font_size: 70
        center_x: root.width * 3 / 4
        top: root.top - 50
        text: "0"
```

Comment: You have a typografic error in your pong.kv, `<PongGame >:`  should be `<PongGame>:` (space)

Comment: Thank you.  I'm using Atom and every time I save the file, it adds a space.  I've disabled the whitespace package, but it still adds the space when saving.  Still studying this issue.  Can't seem to find out why Atom adds the space in the brackets when saving.